# Is there an idiom to "compute" a value?

Tags: swift

*Please excuse me for the poor title. Will update it if something better comes in mind.*

Tested on: **Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)**

I want to take advantage of Swift's lazy stored properties to compute the value of a property while in a "background" queue before accessing it from the main queue.

Here is a class defining a lazy stored property

```
class Cache {

    lazy var heavilyComputational = {
        return 42
    }()
}
```

This is an example usage

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.qnoid.compute", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)){

    let cache = Cache()

    let _ = cache.heavilyComputational

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        debugPrint(cache.heavilyComputational)
    }
}
```

That works.

Warning aside, IMO the intent is not clear.

A lazy property is lazily computed yes but in this case, **the "where", "when" and "why" are equally important and not as clear.**

Tried to clarify intent by being "clever" using a struct like so

```
struct Compute {

    var function: () -> Void {
        didSet{
            function()
        }
    }
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.qnoid.compute", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)){

    let cache = Cache()

    Compute {
        cache.heavilyComputational
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        debugPrint(cache.heavilyComputational)
    }
}
```

but the compiler "outsmart" me by removing the instruction (AFAICT) since the Compute instance isn't used. FWIW, this is on the Debug configuration and I can only assume on Release it will be even more aggressive.

For comparison, this works as expected (*not the didSet call)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.qnoid.compute", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)){

    let cache = Cache()

    let compute = Compute {
        cache.heavilyComputational
    }

    compute.function()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        debugPrint(cache.heavilyComputational)
    }
}
```

but by that time, the whole purpose is defeated.

<s>1. Have I misunderstood something?</s>
2. Is there a native construct to allow for something like this in Swift?
<s>3. If not, is there a way to rewrite this code so that the intent is clear?</s>
4. Why the *didSet* is not called?

*Sample project:* https://github.com/qnoid/compute

Comment: The intent is not clear, let's wrap it into language constructs that hide the intent much more efficiently. If you want to compute something, just call the function `heavilyComputational()`. Calling a function is the clearest expression you can get.

Comment: @Sulthan ditto on using language constructs and the clearest expression that is calling a method. Still, there is 1 problem and 1 drawback with this. In this example, you cannot use cache.heavilyComputational(). Second, IMO merely calling the method, doesn't explain the why in the same way the "Compute" connotation does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a simple answer to this.

```
struct Compute {

    init(f: () -> Void) {
        f()
    }
}
```

Happy with that answer for question 3, the rest remain. Tho, worry I might be bitten by some future compiler optimisation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you kinda realise the problem. As far as I know, didSet won't be triggered if it's in the `init` method.

In your case, when you do

```
Compute {
    cache.heavilyComputational
}
```

It's actually using `init` method of the struct to set the `function` property which will not trigger the `didSet`.

And in your second attempt, since you explicitly call the `function()` which will then call `cache.heavilyComputational`, so you trigger the lazy initialization of `heavilyComputational` manually. It's pretty much equivalent to your original (without the `Compute` struct) method.

---

To make your struct works without calling the function, you have to do some hacks.

```
struct Compute {
    var function: () -> Void = {} {
        didSet{
            function()
        }
    }

    init(function: () -> Void) {
        setFunction(function)
    }

    private mutating func setFunction(function: () -> Void) {
        self.function = function
    }
}
```

So then you can just do

```
Compute {
    cache.heavilyComputational
}
```

For further improvement, I'll have to think about it.